# Django crispy forms prepend box set width

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, django-crispy-forms

I am using crispy forms to make a django form which has several rows. The default behaviour is for the prepend box to be just the size of the text within it. However this looks messy when there are several fields and I would prefer the prepend box to be an equal width for all. An ugly hack is to just pad the prepend boxes that contain shorter strings with spaces but this is obviously not ideal. Any advoice on how to adjust the width of the prepend box to make them equal across fields?

This if the form helper I have where I define the prepend text

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(Field(PrependedText('field1', 'Field1prependtext &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp', wrapper_class='col-md-4 pe-0'))),
            Row(Field(PrependedText('field1', 'Field1prependtextlonger ', wrapper_class='col-md-4 pe-0'))),)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS like:

```
.pe-0 .input-group > .input-group-text {
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean adding this to the wrapper class string. This does not have the desired effect - it simply encases the fields in  a large rectangle

Comment: No, just by adding this CSS style. It respects already your wrapper class.

Comment: Adding to the CSS has no effect

Comment: This does it:.test .input-group>.input-group-prepend {
  flex: 0 0 90%;
}
.test .input-group .input-group-text {
  width: 100%;
}

Comment: I missed to ask which Bootstrap version do you use. So it was a blind guess.